# Deleted Copy Bundle Resources in XCode for the Flutter Project

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, resources, bundle

I accidentally deleted all the resources in XCode Copy Bundle Resources for a Flutter Project.  ChatGPT states that running Flutter build ios will recreate the reources but nothing appears after I clean and build. I manually add the bundles and I get a compile error "Cycle error".  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to recreate all my packages, updated Flutter and all my Pods, and clean and build.  Still no luck.

Comment: Yikes! This sounds super frustrating. Depending on how much code you have in the project, I'd be tempted to re-create it entirely. (I'm not too familiar with Flutter, so I don't exactly know what that entails, but for a "native" project, it would just mean creating a new project, and copying in all the files again.) Good luck!

Comment: I could not figure it out so I just went back to an earlier github commit and started over.  I am good now.